# failed to open session for the virtual machine Oracle developer days

Tags: oracle, session, virtual-machine, oracle-sqldeveloper, virtualbox

this is the first time for me using oracle for my college study, and this is the first time i try to run it but i got this error "The virtual machine 'Oracle Developer Days' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1). More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Asus\VirtualBox VMs\Oracle Developer Days\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'."
i already uninstall my VirtualBox for several times but this thing keep happen

[image]

Comment: I suggest you try the dedicated VirtualBox forums which [you'll find here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Community). You're much more likely to find people with the specific expertise and energy to diagnose your problem there.

Comment: there's a log file in that screenshot, open it, read it...add the contents to your question